# using Matplotlib to draw. I use ax.set_xlabel("X") and ax.set_ylabel("Y") to set axis name.but the following problem occur

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as axisartist

fig = plt.figure("sigmoid",(10,8))
ax = axisartist.Subplot(fig,1,1,1)
fig.add_axes(ax)

ax.axis[:].set_visible(False)
ax.axis["x"] = ax.new_floating_axis(0,0)
ax.axis["y"] = ax.new_floating_axis(1,0)
ax.axis["x"].set_axisline_style("->",size=2.)
ax.axis["y"].set_axisline_style("->",size=2.)
ax.axis["x"].set_axis_direction("bottom")
ax.axis["y"].set_axis_direction("left")

ax.plot(X,Y,color='C2',linewidth=2.0)
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_title("Sigmoid激活函数",fontproperties=font,pad=20)

plt.show()
```

[the result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1ByS.png)
i don't understand why tha axis name of Y is not "Y" but "X".
the picture of above code has showed in the following.
could you help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a [`floating_axis`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/axisartist.html#floatingaxis) from the `axisartist` toolkit, you can set the axis label using the following method, as documented in the [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/axisartist.html#floatingaxis):

```
ax.axis["x"].label.set_text("X")
ax.axis["y"].label.set_text("Y")
```

So in your demo, you would change the `ax.set_xlabel("X")` and `ax.set_ylabel("Y")` lines to the lines above.